# format in excel with multiple conditions

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting, boolean-expression

I am trying to format in Excel using multiple conditions.

If I use:

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()))="_"
```

It works fine, all cells with the value "_" are formatted.

If I use:

```
=MOD(ROW(),2)
```

It also works fine, all cells in odd numbered rows are formatted.

I would like to format only if both conditions are true.
I tried:

```
=AND(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()))="_", MOD(ROW(),2))
```

as well as:

```
=IF(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()))="_", IF(MOD(ROW(),2),TRUE,FALSE),FALSE)
```

How can I combine the two conditions and only highlight cells in odd rows with the value "_"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
=(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()))="_")*ISODD(ROW())
```

[image]

You can try formula without `INDIRECT`:

```
=(A1="_")*ISODD(ROW())
```

Change `A1` to first cell reference from `Applies to` range

Comment: Thank you!  So the false result from the INDIRECT function is taken as a 0 value?

Comment: @Joth Yes. And vice versa - the formula result ```0``` or ```1``` is interpreted as ```FALSE``` or ```TRUE```.

Comment: You may not need to use ```INDIRECT```, see the edit.